# Undefined predicate error in datalog

Tags: datalog

So I'm currently learning datalog. I booted it up and typed in the following:

```
parent(john, michael).
```

and was promptly given an undefined predicate error. From what I understand this should be a correct way to define a relationship in the mock database. What is wrong? I've had a hunt around the internet and can find nothing.

I'm using the Windows 64bit version of the program without the GUI

Comment: I have the same Problem. The tool he is talking about is Datalog Educational System (DES)  (des.sourceforge.net) and the exact error term is :
Warning: Undefined predicate: [parent/1]
{
}
Info: 0 tuples computed.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in Datalog's answer different datalog systems have different behaviors.  If you're looking for a quick-and-dirty way to learn about datalog in in general, you could also try the online interpreter for the "LogiQL" datalog variant: https://repl.logicblox.com/.  (Disclosure: I work for the company that makes LogiQL.)  As a hello-world you could try:

```
=> addblock 'parent("john", "michael").'
Succesfully added block
=> print parent
/-------------------\
| john   | michael  |
\-------------------/
```

Answer (score 2):

What is the name of the datalog system that you are using? Datalog is the name of a language. Different systems accept different variants of the language. Some may require you to declare predicates before using them.

Answer (score 2):

You can find answers to these questions in the user manual of DES, which is in the folder ./doc of the distribution and can also be downloaded from its web page.
Anyway, what you have typed is a query, i.e., you are not trying to assert a new fact. If you want to interactively assert a fact, use the command /assert, as in:

```
DES> /assert parent(john, michael)

DES> parent(john,michael)

{            

  parent(john,michael)

}

Info: 1 tuple computed.
```

The other way to assert Datalog facts (and also rules) is to store them in a file, say parents.dl, and consult it (notice the ending dot after a fact):

Contents of parents.dl:

```
parent(john,michael).
```

End of contents of parents.dl

To consult it:

```
DES> /consult parents             

Info: 1 rule consulted.

DES> parent(john,michael)

{          

  parent(john,michael)

}

Info: 1 tuple computed.
```

Note that the query asks the system whether the fact parent(john,michael) is deduced from its database, which it is deduced indeed. Other uses of queries include variables, as in:

```
DES> parent(X,Y)                  

{             

  parent(john,michael)

}

Info: 1 tuple computed.
```